# Multithreading,Callable,FutureObject

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

How can I return two individual iterated `Set<String>` values in a same method to a `Future` object which is in main method?  I'm using `Callable` since I have to return a set of string values and store them for furthur use.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, it would be the same when you want to return multiple values from any method.  You can always create a wrapper class that holds any number of `Set` values and return that from your `Callable`.

```
private static class MultiSet {
   Set<Integer> set1;
   Set<Integer> set2;
}

private static class MyCallable implements Callable<MultiSet> {
    public MultiSet call() {
        ...
    }
}
```